# Role basesd access control recursive SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlite, rbac

I made the following role based access database schema which is able to hold roles, operations and types. A role can perform a specific operation on a type. Connections to users or types is not important here because this will be application specific. Every of these three tables can have as many parents as they want.

At the moment I'm struggling with a query which outputs every possible combination from the `role_operation_type table`.

Every role should inherit every permission on a types from the ancestors which can be more than one. In my opinion I need three nested recursive with queries for that or is there any faster way to achieve that?

My intention is to put that query in a view and select the needed values when a user requests an operation on a type.

**Here is the database schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `role` (
 `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 `name` VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `role_role` (
 `role_id` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `role`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 `parent_role_id` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `role`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT role_uq UNIQUE (`role_id`, `parent_role_id`),
 CONSTRAINT role_chk CHECK(`role_id` != `parent_role_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `operation` (
 `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 `name` VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `operation_operation` (
 `operation_id` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `operation`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 `parent_operation_id` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `operation`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT operation_uq UNIQUE (`operation_id`, `parent_operation_id`),
 CONSTRAINT operation_chk CHECK(`operation_id` != `parent_operation_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `type` (
 `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 `name` VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `type_type` (
 `type_id` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `type`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 `parent_type_id` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `type`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT type_uq UNIQUE (`type_id`, `parent_type_id`),
 CONSTRAINT type_chk CHECK(`type_id` != `parent_type_id`) 
);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `role_operation_type` (
 `role_id` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `role`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 `operation_id` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `operation`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 `type_id` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `type`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT role_id_operation_id_type_id_uq UNIQUE (`role_id`, `operation_id`, `type_id`)
);


CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS role_role_recursive_view AS
WITH RECURSIVE p(role_id, r, parent_role_id) AS (
    SELECT ROLE.id, ROLE.id, role_role.parent_role_id
    FROM ROLE
    INNER JOIN role_role ON ROLE.id = role_role.role_id

    UNION

    SELECT p.r, p.role_id, role_role.parent_role_id
    FROM p
    INNER JOIN role_role ON p.parent_role_id = role_role.role_id
    WHERE p.r != role_role.parent_role_id
)
SELECT p.role_id, p.parent_role_id FROM p ORDER BY role_id;

CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS operation_operation_recursive_view AS
WITH RECURSIVE o(operation_id, o, parent_operation_id) AS (
    SELECT operation.id, operation.id, operation_operation.parent_operation_id
    FROM operation
    INNER JOIN operation_operation ON operation.id = operation_operation.operation_id

    UNION

    SELECT o.o, o.operation_id, operation_operation.parent_operation_id
    FROM o
    INNER JOIN operation_operation ON o.parent_operation_id = operation_operation.operation_id
    WHERE o.o != operation_operation.parent_operation_id
)
SELECT o.operation_id, o.parent_operation_id FROM o ORDER BY operation_id;

CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS type_type_recursive_view AS
WITH RECURSIVE t(type_id, t, parent_type_id) AS (
    SELECT TYPE.id, TYPE.id, type_type.parent_type_id
    FROM TYPE
    INNER JOIN type_type ON TYPE.id = type_type.type_id

    UNION

    SELECT t.t, t.type_id, type_type.parent_type_id
    FROM t
    INNER JOIN type_type ON t.parent_type_id = type_type.type_id
    WHERE t.t != type_type.parent_type_id
)
SELECT t.type_id, t.parent_type_id FROM t ORDER BY type_id;
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing RBAC / ABAC? There are systems that already implement this OOTB. Grab a library and do not reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1):

Now I will answer to my own question with a solution which works quite well. This is a recursive query and generates every possible combination. This is a recursive query which might be slow when the inheritance level becomes deeper.

```
        CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS role_operation_type_recursive_view AS
        WITH RECURSIVE T(role_id, operation_id, type_id) AS (
            WITH RECURSIVE O(role_id, operation_id, type_id) AS (
                WITH RECURSIVE R(role_id, operation_id, type_id) AS (
                    SELECT role_id, operation_id,type_id
                    FROM role_operation_type

                    UNION

                    SELECT role_role_recursive_view.role_id, R.operation_id, R.type_id
                    FROM R
                    INNER JOIN role_role_recursive_view ON R.role_id = role_role_recursive_view.parent_role_id
                )
                SELECT * FROM R

                UNION

                SELECT O.role_id,operation_operation_recursive_view.parent_operation_id ,O.type_id
                FROM O
                INNER JOIN operation_operation_recursive_view ON O.operation_id = operation_operation_recursive_view.operation_id
            )
            SELECT * FROM O

            UNION

            SELECT T.role_id, T.operation_id, type_type_recursive_view.type_id
            FROM T
            INNER JOIN type_type_recursive_view ON T.type_id = type_type_recursive_view.parent_type_id
        )
        SELECT * FROM T;
```